# android recorder start invalid state 4

Tags: android, audio, recorder

I don't kno why but the start() method throw an error and crash the app:

```
public class Noise extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.noise);
    MediaRecorder recorder=new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    try{
        recorder.prepare();
    }catch(IllegalStateException e){
        Log.d("Error",e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.d("Error",e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recorder.start();
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RecorderTask(recorder), 0, 500);
}
private class RecorderTask extends TimerTask{
    TextView risultato=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.risultato_recorder);
    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    public RecorderTask(MediaRecorder recorder){
        this.recorder = recorder;
    }
    public void run(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                risultato.setText("" + recorder.getMaxAmplitude());
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

if i remove the prepare and the start, it work but return always 0 in the textview.
anyone can help me? this thing make me crazy

this is the logcat: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16047047/log.txt

and in the phone, it crash.

Comment: What is the error (stack trace) that is thrown by the start() method?

Comment: i've added the logcat in the main question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you miss a `recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);` See the documentation for [`MediaRecorder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

At least, this is what the stack trace tells us:

```
11-29 16:04:08.933: W/System.err(9323): java.io.IOException: No valid output file
```

This is the relevant source code for `MediaRecorder.prepare()`:

```
public void prepare() throws IllegalStateException, IOException
{
    if (mPath != null) {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPath);
        try {
            _setOutputFile(fos.getFD(), 0, 0);
        } finally {
            fos.close();
        }
    } else if (mFd != null) {
        _setOutputFile(mFd, 0, 0);
    } else {
        throw new IOException("No valid output file");
    }
    _prepare();
}
```

(you can [read it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/media/MediaRecorder.java#453) on grepcode) The exception is thrown if both the `File` object and the `FileDescriptor` are `null`. So I don't think you can use `MediaRecorder` without supplying a file. You can try the tricky `/dev/null` but I don't know if it works, and can't test right now

Comment: but i don't need it.
i need only to put the getMaxAplitude in the textview

Comment: But maybe the class is designed to work with an output file. You can try using `/dev/null` -  Sorry I can't test right now

Comment: mmm... no now it give me start failed -2147483648.
wait: on the devices now works! but i must understand the outputted value... it seems not the dB

Comment: That is another question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're calling `start()` twice, once in the Activity `onCreate()`, once in the RecorderTask constructor. You should only need one. Without knowing *how* it crashes -- like a stack trace -- it's hard to know more.

Comment: i call it only in the onCreate(), the other is removed

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem might happens with `mediaRecoder.setOutputFormat(value)` Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/37232920/3533092